# Parsing java streams

Tags: java, stream, byte, decode

I am trying to access data from a raw data stream. Before accessing the raw data stream, I must parse/remove any traces of xml. I do this by converting the raw stream to a string array and by iterating through each line to remove the xml.

I can parse/remove the xml from the string okay and I can recreate the data stream. The problem I have is reading through each line and storing each value (year, month, day, power)
The while loop fails with an out of bound exception on the line:
   int year = bb.get(0);

My guess is that this is happening because the newResult string that's created isn't being read correctly through the readLine method. Instead of having a list of raw data, there's only one line of raw data. According to the specifications, there should be 60 (and the length of decResult-1 is 60.

Here is the code below. Can anyone help me to figure out why the while loop isn't iterating through each line? Thanks.

```
try {                   
   HttpRequestBase request = null;
   request = new HttpGet(urlString);
   consumer.sign(request);
   Log.v(TAG, "consumer.sign");
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
   InputStream stream = (InputStream)response.getEntity().getContent();
   String result = convertStreamToString(stream);
   String[] decResult = result.split("<day raw=\"");
   String newResult = ""; 
   if(decResult.length > 1) {
      for(int i=1; i<decResult.length; i++) {
         decResult[i] = decResult[i].replaceAll("\"\\/>", "");
         Log.v(TAG, "DecResult = "+ (decResult[i]).toString());
         decResult[i] = decResult[i].replaceAll("</ted5000_mtu_days>","");
         Log.v("DayData", decResult[i].toString());
         newResult = newResult.concat((decResult[i].toString() + "\n"));
   }
} 

Log.v("DayData", "newResult = "+ newResult);
Log.v("DayData", "End NewResult");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(newResult));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   Log.v("DayData", "****Entering while loop***");
   Log.v("DayData", "Line = " + line);
   String bytes = Base64.decode(line);
   Log.v("DayData", "Received bytes");
   ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes.getBytes());
   Log.v("DayData", "ByteBuffer.wrap");
   bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
   int year = bb.get(0);
   int month = bb.get(1);
   int day = bb.get(2);
   int power = bb.getInt(3);
   Log.i("DayData", "Date: " +  month + "/" + day + "/" + year +  " Power: " + power);
  }     
  Log.v("DayData", "Exiting while loop");
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     Log.e("DayData", "Exception: " + e.toString());
     return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you consider pumping the stream into an XML parser and traversing the DOM tree instead?

Comment: I have tried to parse the XML but it doesn't seem to be in the standard XML format.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ted5000_mtu_day_data -->
<ted5000_mtu_days>
<link type="application/xml" rel="ted5000_mtu" href="/api/v1/users/user_1184/ted5000s/13/mtus.xml"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="ted5000" href="/api/v1/users/user_1184/ted5000s/13.xml"/>
 <day raw="CgsLjTkAAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="/>
<day raw="CgsJljkAAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="/>
 . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an XML parser that suits your needs. From the wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Programming_interfaces):

> Existing APIs for XML processing tend to fall into these categories:
>
> - Stream-oriented APIs accessible from a programming language, for example SAX and StAX.
> - Tree-traversal APIs accessible from a programming language, for example DOM.
> - XML data binding, which provides an automated translation between an XML document and
>     programming-language objects.
> - Declarative transformation languages such as XSLT and XQuery.

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately, this was the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're bombing out on an empty line. Since you already have lots of debug logging you could verify that by changing this line Log.v("DayData", "Received bytes"); to something like this Log.v("DayData", "Received bytes: \""+bytes+"\"");

You probably should still check for this condition, even if you find some other error is causing the problem. If you expect a certain length, you can check that the .limit() on the buffer meets your expectations.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm bombing on an empty line because there is an issue with the parsing. Instead of using a DOM parser, I tried removing the XML elements from the string and retrieve each piece of data from the raw format. I'm assuming there's a fundamental issue with doing this that modifies the raw data format.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a DOM tree. I would use a pull parser instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I wasn't familiar with pull parser but the DOM tree worked okay.

Comment: Are you processing large amounts of data? The DOM will be significantly slower and require gobs more memory. If you're not dealing with a lot of data, it won't matter, but if you are it will make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Fortunately, I'm not dealing with large amounts of data.